# Looking for an AJAX jQuery way to get four field values and send them to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I have an MVC application. I would like to get the values of a variable number of field values such as:

```
field_1, field_2 .. field_4
```

send them to my controller and then change the value of a Div's text based on the response. I never really used jQuery for anything like this. Do I need to use JSON to pack up the values and if so how do I unpack them on server. Is it something I can do easily? I hope for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think,

you can find an answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701044/jquery-ajax-create-multiple-objects-in-single-ajax-call-to-rails/5701160#5701160). You should use the 'post' method for sending and receiving the data.

If you want to read more about JSON objects in different language read http://www.json.org

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inputs are in a from tag you can get the id of the form, serialize it, create an ajax request to the server, process it, then return data.  It's look something like this.

```
function sendToServer() {
    var sendData = $('#myForm').serialize;
    $.get('/url/to/server/', sendData, function(returnData){
        //This is called on success
        $('#myDiv').html = returnData;
    });
}
```

Now this assumes also that the div has an id 'myDiv' and that returnData is already html formatted.  It doesn't have to be you can do more processing inside the success call back

How to make the Ajax Call
[Jquery .get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

How to serialize a form
[Jquery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Please I am using Microsoft MVC3. I don't want to serialize the form. I just need some way to get the value of 2,3 ... 4 or more fields and then feed them back to the controller. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Brombombs answer is mostly complete.  The '.serialize()' essentially takes the name of the html elements and the value and puts it into a JSON array structure. When you do a .get or a .post and have that data as the data to send, they will be available to PHP in global variables.  .get the variables will be found in the $_GET variable and if doing a post, a $_POST variable.

for example

```
<form id="myForm">
<input name="firstName">John</input>
</form>
```

`$('#myForm').serialize()` returns a json
`{ 'firstName' : 'John' }`

and doing a .post... php can access this as

`echo $_POST['firstName'];`
//prints John

Comment: I guess I am confused. I'm using MVC not php so that's the first thing confusing me. Also I need to get data from a number of different elements with almost the same name: field_1, field_2

Comment: `...Also I need to get data from a number of different elements with almost the same name: field_1, field_2...` this is what the jQuery.serialize() function does... Takes all of the elements that are 'children' of the form and puts them into a nice little array... all done in one small jquery function call... In regards to the MVC... i think its absurdly convoluted and do not use it... but a quick seach here at SOF sugggests... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698096/simplest-way-to-post-post-data-from-mvc-dialog-to-controller